# wso2emm agent - default server IP Address

Tags: wso2-iot

How can I set the IP address of the server so that users don't need to enter it during the enrollment process?

In the manual it refers to "changing the Android agent SERVER_PROTOCOL to https and SERVER_PORT to 9443 in the constant.java file that is in the /modules/mobile-agents/android/client/client/src/main/java/org/wso2/emm/agent/utils directory." but not how to set the server address.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Dilshan thankyou for the tip, I made the changes as you suggested but it has made no difference. The QR code scanner gets the address, the phone connects and downloads the Agent. When the Agent opens the user still has to type in the address of the server - this is no good - there must be a way to fix this - I hope.

Answer (score 0):

This is for Android. For server configurations refer [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM200/General+Server+Configurations). Change following entries.

```
<HostName>www.wso2.org</HostName>
<MgtHostName>www.wso2.org</MgtHostName>
```

Answer (score 0):

Steve Let me be clear what you want to archive is to remove the server url text filed from the agent applications is it ?

In order to accomplish that you need to modify the the android agent and compile and generate a customer .apk file.

You can find the source for the android agent [here](https://github.com/wso2/product-emm/tree/master/modules/mobile-agents/android/client).

If you examine [ServerDetails.java](https://github.com/wso2/product-emm/blob/master/modules/mobile-agents/android/client/client/src/main/java/org/wso2/emm/agent/ServerDetails.java) and [RegistrationActivity.java](https://github.com/wso2/product-emm/blob/master/modules/mobile-agents/android/client/client/src/main/java/org/wso2/emm/agent/RegistrationActivity.java) files you can see the server id is retrieve from the user and used in `regiterDevice` method.
You have the freedom of changing that and hard code your server domain or IP address there.